# Metadata filtering on libraries for users having "Read only" access

Tags: sharepoint-server, read-only, file-metadata, restricted-access

We have a library where all the files have been tagged using 5 Metadata terms for each (so 5 Metadata term sets, and a lot more terms underneath each). The problem is that all users can see all the Metadata filters, ,but only click of a particular term the view displayed is "There are no files in the view ". Without applying any metadata filters, all the files are visible to users with Read access.

Already tried
1. Changed the term's Navigation setting to "Simple Link or Header" - Did not work

The only solution was 
1. To give edit access to the users for the list and its items

Any other workaround is welcome